# Вывести sidebar только на главной странице сайта WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

На сайте уже подключен (зарегистрирован) сайдбар. Мне надо в него добавить новый блок с текстом и ссылками. И еще необходимо чтобы этот блок выводился только на главной странице.

Зарегистрировала сайдбар `sidebar3` в [functions.php](https://jsfiddle.net/Lr9psypj/). Создала отдельный файл sidebar3.php:

```
<div id="left-column">
<?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Sidebar3') ) : ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

В home.php указала путь:

```
<?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/sidebar3.php'); ?>
```

В админке на странице виджеты добавила текст и ссылки в виджете Sidebar3.
Но сайдбрар не выводится. Что не правильно делаю? Как вывести дополнительный сайдбар но только на главной странице?

Comment: Марина, старайтесь не плодить темы, Вы задали подобный вопрос в предыдущей теме, на который я ответил

Answer (score 1):

Нужно сделать проверку [is_front_page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page)

```
     <div id="left-column">
      <?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Sidebar3') ) : ?>
     <?php endif; ?>
```

Если Вы зарегистрировали sidebar, создайте для него шаблон к примеру `sidebar-main.php` и подключите его `<?php is_front_page(get_sidebar('main')); ?>`

Answer (score 1):

Добрый день!

Создайте файл sidebar-main.php в папке темы и разместите следующий код:

```
<?php 
    //Проверяем наличие сайдбара и выводим его виджеты
    if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar("Simple Sidebar") ) : 
    endif; 
?>
```

В файл functions.php в папке вашей темы добавьте код:

```
<?php
    //Создаём сайдбар в теме (регистрируем)
    if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') )
    register_sidebar(array(
        'id' => 'sidebar-1',
        'name' => 'Simple Sidebar', 
        'before_widget' => '<div class="widget">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h6 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title' => '</h6>',
    ));

?>
```

В шаблоне страницы (front-page.php, home.php) добавьте код в нужном месте вывода сайдбара:

```
<?php
    //Проверяем, главная ли страница у нас показывается
    if(is_front_page())
    {
        //Выводим сайдбар из файла sidebar-main.php
        get_sidebar('main');
    }

?>
```

**Дополнительная информация для вас**

```
<?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/sidebar3.php'); ?>
```

Подключение файлов через include в wordpress не приветствуется, используйте функцию get_template_part();

**Полезные ссылки:**

[is_front_page()](http://wp-kama.ru/function/is_front_page)

[get_sidebar()](http://wp-kama.ru/function/get_sidebar)

[get_template_part()](http://wp-kama.ru/function/get_template_part)